# solr data import handler not able to index data

Tags: solr

Data config.xml is as follows

```
<dataConfig>  
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solrdata" user="root" password="root"  />  
    <document name="cars">  

        <entity name="car" query="SELECT color FROM solrdata.car ">  

          <field column="color" name="color" />  

        </entity>  

    </document>  
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml is as follsws

```
field name="color" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

i checked in debug mode its getting data but not able to process it

output of debug mode is as follows:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 312
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "data-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "full-import",
  "mode": "debug",
  "documents": [
    {
      "COLOR": [
        "red"
      ]
    },
    {
      "COLOR": [
        "silver"
      ]
    },
    {
      "COLOR": [
        "oii"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "verbose-output": [],
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "3",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2013-03-07 15:49:14",
    "Total Documents Processed": "0",
    "Total Documents Failed": "3",
    "Time taken": "0:0:0.281"
  },
  "WARNING": "This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future."
}
```

Comment: Do you have a "uniqueKey" field in your schema.xml? How do you construct it for each document being indexed?

Comment: i am new to solr i just added this one field in my existing schema.xml.

Answer (score 3):

You will have a **uniqueKey** for each document to identify it uniquely (Can be considered similiar to the **PrimaryKey** in Databases).

Modify your entity in data-config.xml as follows:

```
<entity name="car" query="SELECT color,id FROM solrdata.car ">  

  <field column="id" name="id" />  
  <field column="color" name="color" />  

</entity>
```

**Note:** The field id is your **primaryKey** for the table car.

In your schema.xml file, add the following line,

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Also, make sure that the following text,

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

in your schema.xml is not commented out.

Now, restart your Solr Web-application and do a Full-import.

Comment: The `<field>` elements in `<entity>` are nor necessary in your example as column names and "field" names are the same.

Answer (score 3):

I can read from the import handler response:

```
"Total Documents Failed": "3"
```

Looks to me as if your query has some problems or if the loaded schema doesn't "match" the DIH ouput. A `<uniqueKey>` field is not required although highly recommended. But the missing unique key declaration should lead to that error.

Have a look at the "logging" page on the admin console. If the data import handler has problems with the query then you'll find a log entry there.

And don't forget to refresh the schema and the DIH config file if you've applied any changes while the solr instance is running.

Answer (score 0):

Some specific fields, including *version*, should not be in the list of your fields.  (fl="*" this is contains all fields)
Try each field individually with the corresponding id

fl="id,color"